# Whats the best way of designing a table with one timestamp value and multiple rows and columns of data?

Tags: database, database-design, database-relations

Each filename indicates when the data was recorded i.e one data file per minute. For example, 2019-11-21 08:00:00, 2019-11-21 08:00:01 and so on.

Each file has 4 columns of data that consists of multiple rows. All values of the file corresponds to one time instance (filename).

[image]

I want to store the data in relational database table but i am struggling how to relate the time information with data.

One solution i thought is to append the time value for all the rows in file. But that is too much data redundancy. Any other idea to relate one time instance to all of the data in file? How can we do it in a table? I get one file per minute with all the data in it.

I am using MS SQL Server.

Comment: Does any column or combination of columns uniquely identify a row? Based on your image I'm guessing not, i.e. I assume identical rows are possible. Is that right?

Comment: Do any columns depend on or derive from any others? Is there a deterministic relationship between the values of any of the columns? For example, is the third column always the same as the first column?

Comment: @reaanb They are real time measurements so there is no guarantee that they can be different or same. in short yes, idential rows are possible.

No, each column is a measured quantity.

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database table, each row should represent a unique fact. If the date and time when a measurement was made is important, then it should be recorded in the same way as the other values that define such measurements. Your concern with value redundancy is likely a case of premature optimization. The relational model is concerned with eliminating redundant associations, not eliminating redundant values. I recommend you include a timestamp column and record the date and time for each entry.

Comment: Yes i agree. That seems to be only solution. In other words, one-to-many relation could be designed by having a second table that connect timestamps and an index. That index could be appended as column into the data file as shown above. Its basically the same thing, but in this was the index would be repeated instead of time stamp values.